# Spyder error: 'int' object is not callable but no error in different IDE

Tags: python, spyder, python-idle

I have this weird problem i need help with. I have this code I want run in Spyder but I keep getting error stating

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

```
s ='abcdefgbobaaaaabob'
end = 3
bobs = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    finder = s[i:end]
    if finder == 'bob':
        bobs += 1
    end += 1
print('Number of times bob occurs is: '+ str(bobs))
```

The weird part is that when I run the same code in IDLE, it works fine and gives the results I needed. I even tried running the code in pythontutor.com, no error.

Can someone please tell why this is happening!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when you have an object that is an integer number, but your code tries to use it as if it were a function. For example:

- you're using a function that expects another function as one of its arguments, but you passed it an integer instead, or
- you have overridden a function by assigning an integer value to the same name.

It doesn't look like the first of these is an issue here, so perhaps you have accidentally overridden one of the functions you are using?

```
>>> str(3)
'3'
>>> str = 17
>>> str(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

In Spyder you can check this in the **Variable Explorer** tab, and either right-click it and choose `Remove`, or type (e.g.) `del(str)` in the Python console to delete the incorrect assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder saves the variables that you have created earlier. you can check these created variables in the variable explorer tab.

If any variable present there, and you are using the same variable as a function in any python program. it will throw the error "int object is not callable" or "'str' object is not callable" depending on the variable that is present in variable explorer.

Solution:

1. Just remove such variables from Variable explorer by right click on them
2. type del(variable_Name) in the console. eg.del(len) or del len

Please check the screenshot -spyder IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran it using Spyder too, and it worked well. Are you using Python3 ?

Comment: Yeah im using Python3

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: Can you give more information about your problem maybe